# How can I put this into one function?

Tags: jquery, css

```
$(".home").click(function(){
    $("#bg").removeClass("dungeonsbg bgsbg arenasbg specgearbg").addClass("homebg");
});
$(".dungeons").click(function(){
    $("#bg").removeClass("homebg bgsbg arenasbg specgearbg").addClass("dungeonsbg");
});
$(".arenas").click(function(){
    $("#bg").removeClass("homebg bgsbg dungeonssbg specgearbg").addClass("arenasbg");
});
$(".bgs").click(function(){
    $("#bg").removeClass("homebg dungeonsbg arenasbg specgearbg").addClass("bgsbg");
});
$(".specgear").click(function(){
    $("#bg").removeClass("homebg bgsbg arenasbg specgearbg").addClass("specgearbg");
});
```

.home, .dungeons etc. are A tags within a div called navigationMenu.
Just can't get my head around it, and I would probably reuse the same logic for other things on the page.  Ideally it would take a value from what was clicked on and add the new class with that value so that if I added more links it would just automatically work.

Comment: What's the logic? Upon clicking on an element with some specific class, it should remove all (?) classes from `#bg` and assign it the specific class of the clicked element? Do the clicked elements have other classes as well, or just one of the five listed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming each click class only has the one class and that `#bg` has no other classes than these you can just completely overwrite `#bg`s className with the necessary one:

```
$(".home, .dungeons, .arenas, .bgs, .specgear").click(function(){
  $('#bg')[0].className = this.className + 'bg';
});
```

Comment: This works great for what I need.  Just a question what is the [0] for?  Is that selecting the first instance of #bg? if so why would u want that since there is only 1 instance of any id on the page.

Comment: No, the [0] is to unwrap the jQuery wrapper to get at the DOM HTMLElement in order to access the className property so that we can overwrite all classes with `homebg`, `dungeonsbg`, etc.  Essentially the same as what @deceze did, except he got the DOM element directly.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".home, .dungeons, .arenas, .bgs, .specgear").click(function(){
    $("#bg").attr('class', $(this).attr('class') + 'bg');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that all elements in question only have one class:

```
$('.home, .dungeons, .arenas, .bgs, .specgear').click(function () {
    document.getElementById('bg').className = this.className + 'bg';
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution could be like so:

```
$('#navigationMenu a').click(function() {
    $('#bg').removeClass().addClass($(this).attr('class') + 'bg');
});
```

This does assume that #bg doesn't have any classes, and the anchors only have one class.